# Comunication between Android and Arduino

Tags: hc-05

I am trying send data from an Arduino to an android device with bluetooth.
I want to send a date y and when it arrives, turn on a led, but when I send the data nothing happened.
This is my code for Arduino (I use the bluetooth module hc-05)

```cpp
char entrada;
void setup()
{ 
pinMode(8,OUTPUT);
Serial.begin(9600);
digitalWrite(8,LOW);
}
void loop()
{
   if(Serial.available()>0)
{
 entrada=Serial.read();
 if(entrada=='1')
 {
    digitalWrite(8,LOW);
    Serial.println("1");
  }
 }
```

And in the side of android i have this codec with my handler and thread for inputstream and outputstream

```cpp
public void run()
    {
        byte[] espera=new byte [256];
        int esperaalmacen;
        while (true) {
            try {
                esperaalmacen=entradadatos.read(espera);
                mhandler.obtainMessage(MENSAJELEYENDO,esperaalmacen,-1,espera).sendToTarget();
            }catch (IOException e){}
        }
```

And in my activity main I have:

```cpp
       @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg)
    {
        super.handleMessage(msg);
        switch (msg.what)
        {
            case CONECTADO:
                //ManejarDatos msjre = new ManejarDatos((BluetoothSocket)msg.obj);
                msjre = new ManejarDatos((BluetoothSocket)msg.obj);
                break;
            case MENSAJELEYENDO:
                byte[] readBuf = (byte[])msg.obj;
                String string = new String(readBuf);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), string, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

My modulo I have configured as slave.

Comment: What is pin 8 doing? And why is it set to LOW two times but never set HIGH?

Comment: have you tried establishing a master-slave setup using I2C?